What does the double derivative tell us?
What does the double derivative tell us about a function? Why is it required for finding the local extrema but not for the absolute extrema?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It seems like this question already has an answer try looking here What is the meaning of second derivative?
